# What construction is "lorsqu'il est entré une femme"?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, pronoms-impersonnels

I wondered if anyone could help explain what is happening grammatically in the following sentence, taken from Camus' "L'étranger":

> J'avais déjà commencé à manger lorsqu'il est entré une bizarre petite femme qui m'a demandé ...

I think I understand the sentence; my translation is "I had already started eating **when in came** a strange, small woman who asked me ..."

However, I am particularly interested in "**lorsqu'il est entré une femme**" — I have never seen this construction before and wonder what it is and if it is very common.  Could Camus have also written "lorsqu'une bizarre petite femme est entrée"?

---

Je me demandais si quelqu'un pouvait aider à expliquer ce qui se passe grammaticalement dans l’extrait suivant de *L'étranger* de Camus:

> J'avais déjà commencé à manger lorsqu'il est entré une bizarre petite femme qui m'a demandé ...

Je pense que je comprends la phrase ; ma traduction est « I had already started eating **when in came** a strange, small woman who asked me ... ».

Cependant, ce qui m'intéresse particulièrement est « **lorsqu'il est entré une femme** » — je n'ai jamais vu cette construction et je me demande ce dont il s'agit et si cette construction est très courante. Pourrait-il avoir également écrit « lorsqu'une bizarre petite femme est entrée » ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is absolutely correct.

Regarding the construction, it is quite common in litterature or formal speeches. Camus could have written *lorsqu'une bizarre petite femme est entrée* but the level would have been less litterary.

Technically speaking, I would say this construction is "dummy subject (*il*) + verb (*entre*) + real subject (*une femme*)", where *il* stands for *une femme* ([see definition of *il*, section B.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/il)).

--

Ta compréhension de la phrase est bonne.

Ce type de construction est assez fréquent dans la littérature, ou encore dans certains discours. Camus aurait pu écrire *lorsqu'une bizarre petite femme est entrée*, mais le niveau de la phrase aurait été moins soutenu.

Techniquement, je dirais que cette construction se décompose comme suit : "sujet apparent (*il*), verbe (*entre*), sujet réel (*une femme*)", où *il* est employé dans sa tournure impersonnelle comportant un sujet réel ([voir définition de *il*, sens B.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/il))

Comment: Merci Shlublu!  Alors, il n'y a pas de mystère; ce n'est qu’une figure de style!

Comment: Effectivement, pas de mystère ici ! "Juste" du style :)