# The subject in "Qu’il est loin le temps"

Tags: grammaire, exclamations

> [Qu’il est loin le temps](http://madame.lefigaro.fr/societe/anna-wintour-voit-hillary-clinton-presidente-110713-439304)

Which is the subject: *il*, *le temps*, or even *que*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nous avons ici un **sujet réel** (*le temps*) et un **sujet apparent** (*il*). Le sujet apparent se substitue au sujet réel tant que ce dernier n'est pas énoncé.

Cette construction est analogue à celle vue [dans cette autre question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6959/what-construction-is-lorsquil-est-entre-une-femme/6960#6960) (*lorsqu'il est entré une femme*).

La subtilité, ici c'est l'emploi de *que* : il exprime une exclamation ([voir définition du TLF, sens C-](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/que)).

La phrase

> *Qu'il est loin le temps (où Anna Wintour ne se gênait pas) !*

pourrait donc se réécrire ainsi:

> *Que le temps (où Anna Wintour ne se gênait pas) est loin !*

Comment: In other words, _qu'il est loin le temps_ is a more formal or literary way of saying _que le temps est loin_?

Comment: @Indoxica Yes, exactly.

Comment: @Indoxica and both are more formal than *le temps est loin où*

Answer (score 0):

The subject is "il".

Here "il" replaces everything from "le temps où" to the end of the sentence.

"Que" is here used as an exclamative adverb to emphasize the fact that this time is really far from now.

> What big teeth you have got!
>
> *Que vous avez de grandes dents !*